# How to perfectly align textarea and canvas fillText

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, textarea

A feature like text box is common in whiteboard applications. Usually the text on canvas fades and the text area over it shows for editing the content when a user clicks the text box.

When I tried to implement this feature, I found it's hard to align the text area and the rendered text.

In the following example, I purposely make them overlap to demonstrate the offset they have in y axis.

**Black**: textarea
**Red**: fillText

[image]

```js
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import './App.css';

const WIDTH = 300;
const HEIGHT = 300;
const FONT_SIZE = 80;

function App() {
  const canvasRef = useRef()

  useEffect(() => {
    const canvas = canvasRef.current
    canvas.width = WIDTH * devicePixelRatio
    canvas.height = HEIGHT * devicePixelRatio
    canvas.style.width = `${WIDTH}px`
    canvas.style.height = `${HEIGHT}px`
    const context = canvas.getContext('2d')
    context.fillStyle = 'red'
    context.font = `${FONT_SIZE * devicePixelRatio}px sans-serif`
    const metrics = context.measureText('M')
    context.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH * devicePixelRatio, HEIGHT * devicePixelRatio)
    context.fillText('Hello', 0, metrics.fontBoundingBoxAscent)
    context.fillText('World', 0, metrics.fontBoundingBoxAscent + FONT_SIZE * devicePixelRatio)
  }, [])


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="container">
        <canvas ref={canvasRef} />
        <textarea value="Hello World" style={{ width: `${WIDTH}px`, height: `${HEIGHT}px` }}/>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```css
.App {
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;

  textarea {
    position: absolute;
    inset: 0;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    resize: none;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 1;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    font-size: 80px;
    background-color: transparent;
    font-family: sans-serif;
  }
}
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/sad-orla-jymn8l?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsoi3ud900063b6f1p1fp5bl%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsoi3ud900023b6f4bjpdzca%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsoi3ud900033b6f2yptwxxh%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsoi3ud900053b6fsbywxjx8%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B46.24502712798962%252C53.75497287201038%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clsoi3ud900023b6f4bjpdzca%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsoi3ud900013b6fkblc4gg9%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Findex.js%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltdr6vl300023b6oaf2w92pe%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A25%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A1%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A25%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A1%257D%255D%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252FApp.js%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsoi3ud900023b6f4bjpdzca%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522cltdr6vl300023b6oaf2w92pe%2522%257D%252C%2522clsoi3ud900053b6fsbywxjx8%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsoi3ud900053b6fsbywxjx8%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522cltdu1d9l001o3b6i181u9l94%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltdu1d9l001o3b6i181u9l94%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%2522clsoi3ud900033b6f2yptwxxh%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsoi3ud900033b6f2yptwxxh%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A10%257D)

Does anyone know what makes the difference between the text positioning?

Comment: That's one of the biggest interop issues in canvas2D, browsers can't agree on what should be the various `textBaseline` values actually based on. TextMetrics is also an interop nightmare... FWIW, in Firefox your code renders almost as expected (I have a 1px difference on a x2 monitor, so I'd say a possible rounding issue somewhere).